# Html.DropDownList disable if it is Empty

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, html-select

I am new to MVC and working on an MVC4 Application.

What I wan to do is I want to disable my Dropdown if it is empty.

View->

```
@Html.DropDownList("UserName", null, string.Empty)
```

Controller->

```
ViewBag.UserName = new SelectList(lstUserName, "username", "username");
```

UserName is my viewbag which contains the list of items to fill dropdown.

Now if lstUserName is empty,I want to disable the DropDown..How can I achieve that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if (@ViewBag.UserName.Items.Count == 0)
{
@Html.DropDownList("UserName", null, string.Empty, new { @disabled=true})
}
else
{
 @Html.DropDownList("UserName", null, string.Empty)
}
```

You could use `@readonly` aswell, instead of `@disabled`.

Comment: Your first version wouldn't work. As far as I know, `disabled` is based on the presence of the attribute, not the value contained within.

Comment: @Farzi Try for List of one item.

Comment: @SimonBelanger I tested this out on my own machine and it works for me. I am using MVC4 tho, maybe it doesn't work in older versions.

Comment: @Thousand It will work for list with 0 items. Disabled="false" is still disabling a field. Check the [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.12.1) or better yet, if you have chrome, right click the comment box click inspect element and add an attribute with `disabled='false'`. It will be disabled. If your browser is enabling the box, it's not a standard behavior and should be avoided. Nothing to do with MVC, this is an HTML specification.

Comment: @SimonBelanger ah indeed, i just tested it and it doesn't work. The second option still does though.

Comment: Its not working..Sorry i incorrect your answer..its disabling the dropdown even if it has items.

Comment: @Thousand Yes, second option works. ;) Farzi, the second option would work, though. Try it out.

Comment: @Farzi the second option will work :) i removed the first one from my answer

Comment: Yep..!!Second one worked..Thanks Thousand and Much Thanks to u @Simon for correcting it out at first point itself..:)